# In a Rails 3.2.13 app, I'm generating an index incorrectly

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a Rails 3.2.13 app I am using the query_reviewer gem to improve my database performance.

The code generating the SQL is:

```
@seo_keywords = SeoKeyword.order("category, keyword")
```

It generated the following SQL warning:

```
MSG: No index was used here. In this case, that meant scanning 64 rows.
SQL: SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `seo_keywords`.* FROM `seo_keywords` ORDER BY category, keyword
```

So I generated the following db migration:

```
  def up
    add_index :seo_keywords, :category
    add_index :seo_keywords, :keyword
  end
```

The migration added the indices to the table as indicated by the schema:

```
  add_index "seo_keywords", ["category"], :name => "index_seo_keywords_on_category"
  add_index "seo_keywords", ["keyword"], :name => "index_seo_keywords_on_keyword"
```

I restarted the server, loaded the page and got the same error. I suppose I'm creating the index incorrectly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you include the Rails code.  It seems like you are doing something like `SeoKeyword.all`

Comment: Right, so the Rails code will load *every* SeoKeword in your data base; there is no `where` clause to limit it down, nor is there something like a `limit`/`offset` for pagination.  So there is no index for the DB to use.  If you want to use your `keyword` or `category` indexes, you need to filter on them.

Comment: If you put your answer in an answer, I'll select it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases (and doubtless in only some RDBMSs), it can be more efficient for some purposes to use an index to perform an order by instead of sorting the records as a separate step in the query execution.

The major advantage of this is that it brings back the first rows very much sooner for large data sets.

However, it has the disadvantages of needing a linguistic-sort index for some character ordering situations, and being generally less efficient in terms of accessing the data so the last rows to be returned may come back later with an index-assisted order-by.

Also, where you are accessing every row of a table with only a small number of rows (and where they are not scattered over a table that is largely empty space) it is often just as efficient to full-scan the table rather than use even a unique index.

These subtleties are very difficult to take account of, and just about every method external to a database that attempts to provide a 100% complete "this is what indexes you need" solution is going to be flawed in some way, so the results always need to be seasoned with some insider database knowledge.

In this case (selecting all of 64 rows and ordering by two columns) what might make a difference is  composite index:

```
add_index "seo_keywords", ["category", "keyword"], :name => "index_seo_keywords_on_category_keyword"
```

However if they are character strings then a special index may be required (I'm no mysql expert I'm afraid).

Also, dependent on whether mysql indexes nulls, you might need to ensure that category and/or keyword are constrained to not nul at the database level.